# Selected tab index C#

Tags: c#, .net

**I have a array 
private `TabPage[] tp = new TabPage[10]`
how can i get index**( array index, not tab index ) **of selected tab ?**

diference between **array index** and **tab index**

Example : i selected a tab. **array index** can be 1 but information contained in tp[8]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var SelectedArrayTabIndex = Array.IndexOf(tp, SelectedTab);
```